# How to get object value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a croppie jquery plugin.All things going good.After resizing an image ,I am not able to get the dataurl from the promise object .Please help me in this.
Here is the screenshot of the data that I am getting on the click of button.
http://prntscr.com/awi9co

The Code is below

```
var basic = $('#divLoadLogo').croppie({
    viewport: {
        width: 150,
        height: 50
    },
    enableOrientation: true
});
basic.croppie('bind', {
    url: Url,
    points: [77, 469, 280, 739],

});
$("#SaveResizeImage").click(function() {
    var CanvasData = basic.croppie('result', 'canvas'); //This contains the promise object
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/User/SaveResizedCanvasImage',
        data: '{ "imageData" : "' + CanvasData + '" }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.success) {

                alert('image is resized');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `basic.croppie('bind', {
                url: Url,
                points: [77, 469, 280, 739],
            }).then(function(){//HERE});` ?

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
var basic = $('#divLoadLogo').croppie({
    viewport: {
        width: 150,
        height: 50
    },
    enableOrientation: true
});
basic.croppie('bind', {
    url: Url,
    points: [77, 469, 280, 739],

});
$("#SaveResizeImage").click(function() {
    basic.croppie('result', 'canvas').then(function(CanvasData){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/User/SaveResizedCanvasImage',
        data: '{ "imageData" : "' + CanvasData + '" }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.success) {

                alert('image is resized');
            }
        }
    });
    });

});
```